# classes from another of my typescript files are not highlighted

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-2017

I'm using typescript in visual studio, normally classes get highlighted well, when I import them, but my classes from other files are not highlighted - is there anything I need to configure for this?
[image: Screenshot of problem in VS]

I'm using visual studio 2017, 15.3.4

Comment: Add your `tsconfig.json` to your question, if your project have one.

Comment: It happens to me with or without a tsconfig.json. In this example I just created a new project based on the Empty node.js web project template.

I've added the code to github:
https://github.com/noam-honig/demo-class-not-highlighted-problem

Comment: Try putting `"module": "commonjs"` and `"moduleResolution": "node"` in your `tsconfig.json` under [`"compillerOptions"`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html).

Comment: Done that  - didn't help.
Can you have a look at the github source?

Comment: If that source was generated by visual studio I'm not sure how that is supposed to work. I'd recommend you to start with a more simple setup by following a TypeScript tutorial that uses npm and use VSCode instead of Visual Studio, this will help you to get started.

Comment: @cvsguimaraes - the source is the typescript template with visual studio.

With vs code  it works fine - it's the highlighting in Visual Studio that doesn't work for classes that are imported